# 3D SumIf using List to loop all sheets final fix needed

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following to make a list of all the sheet names in the sheet summary in   `cell AI1`,  it then deletes the top 3, selects from `AI4` to the bottom and names the range "Invoices"

I am trying to use this to do a sumif Formula over all the sheets. It works pasting it into a cell manually 
but when in VBA,from `'"&Invoices&"'!$A$2006:$A$3005"),$A3,INDIRECT("'"&Invoices&"'!B$2006:B$3005")))"`

Onwards it is reading it as a comment (in green)

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets("Summary").Range("AI1")(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

Sheets("Summary").Select
Sheets("Summary").Range("AI1:AI3").Clear
Sheets("Summary").Activate
Sheets("summary").Range(ActiveSheet.Range("AI4"),
ActiveSheet.Range("AI4").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Name = "Invoices"
Sheets("summary").Range("B3").Formula =    "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Invoices&"'!$A$2006:$A$3005"),$A3,INDIRECT("'"&Invoices&"'!B$2006:B$3005")))"
```

Comment: Your problem is that VBA thinks the " is the end of the string.  You can escape them by replacing " with "" inside the string.

Comment: This may seem like a silly Question but where should I put the second "!!!

Comment: every time you use " in your fomula put "".  Except the one to indicate the start of the formula and the one to indicate the end of it.

Comment: Good man, works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment:
VBA thinks that " is the end of the string, so if you want it to actually be treated as a character you need to escape it as "".
Your code should be:

```
Sheets("summary").Range("B3").Formula =     "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!$A$2006:$A$3005""),$A3,INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!B$2006:B$3005"")))"
```

The easy way to check this when there are lots of characters is to write it in the immediate window. I put

```
? "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!$A$2006:$A$3005""),$A3,INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!B$2006:B$3005"")))"
```

to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
 so for anyone else who needs this, this is how it was done in full

```
 *****'list all the sheet names in cell AI1 of the sheet summary*****
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Sheets("Summary").Range("AI1")(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
***'clear the first 3 entries in AI as i didnt need the first three sheet names***
Sheets("Summary").Select
Sheets("Summary").Range("AI1:AI3").Clear
***'select the first sheet name, which is in AI4 as we cleard the first 3 to the last used cell, e.g Ctrl.Shift.down*** 
Sheets("Summary").Activate
Sheets("summary").Range(ActiveSheet.Range("AI4"),    ActiveSheet.Range("AI4").End(xlDown)).Select
***' Name the range invoices***
Selection.Name = "Invoices"
' ***Formula to do a sumIf looping all the shets in the named range Invoices***
Sheets("summary").Range("B3").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!$A$2006:$A$3005""),$A3,INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!B$2006:B$3005"")))"
```